# Sphinx Unexpected section title - numpydoc

Tags: python, numpy, python-sphinx, numpydoc

I can not make Sphinx work correctly with numpy format.
I am testing with this [example](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/example.py), executing "make html", but I get several warnings to recognize Parameters, Notes, Returns, etc. For example:

```
SEVERE: Unexpected section title.
ERROR: Unexpected indentation.
also
WARNING: Inline emphasis start-string without end-string.
WARNING: Literal block expected; none found
```

This question has been already asked, but I have no success after searching and trying for hours.

What I have done until now:

- installed Sphinx v1.3.5
- updated `numpydoc` to the version 0.5
- added the extensions `numpydoc`, `sphinxcontrib.napoleon`, and `sphinx.ext.napoleon` to the `conf.py` file.
- tried rst2html docum.txt docum.html
- As I had the idea that it was not using numydoc, I wrote an incorrect name as extension and it gave an error (as it should be, so I think it is identifing numpydoc).
- added `numpydoc_show_class_members = False` to `conf.py`
- removing the whole previous html output

Any suggestion or hint of what is wrong? What could I try?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow. Tell us more of what you tried otherwise, you'll get the same suggestions you've read

Comment: Whenever I've had issues like that, something is indented a space or two in that I didn't see.  Or, I forgot some newlines.  Are there any line numbers?    Another thought: use binary search.  Comment out HALF the document and see the problem still occurs.  Figure out which half the problem is in, then keep trying until you isolate the problem to a few lines.

Comment: Hi. I isolated and fixed each Warning, and I am really surprised. It looks like Sphinx is not recognizing the sections. The example I build is the one provided in numpydoc documentation and the problems are: 1. * inside the code is identified as Inline emphasis, 2. indentation is required for code after "::" (Literal block) in documentation, 3. there is error in indentation of the sections (parameters, returns, etc), 4. I can see the “”“ (from the documentation) in the html. Does the python code needs to be adapted always or is something not working good for me?

Comment: Hello, this is the first time I introduce a question, I eddited it because the reply button suggest to _add information to the question_ if the problem is better explained, instead of replying here. Going back to the question, I am not using both `sphinxcontrib.napoleon` and `sphinx.ext.napoleon` at the same time, but I tried to solve the problem with both. After testing more my question would be: _my Sphinx is not recognizing all numpy style , such as indentation inside functions, etc_. Should I just start a totally new question after having some things more clear and leave this here?

Comment: Thanks, but I still thinking that the problem is exaclty the same, my new question might make it looks nicer, and maybe more clear, but the problem is the same as described in the original question.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problems in the question. I don't see any of the errors or warnings. I had to remove `from my_module import my_func, other_func` from example.py that you link to, but otherwise it works.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that I was using numpydoc to document a module directly with `.. toctree:: filename`, but it has to be used with `.. automodule:: filename`. There is more information on how to use it here: http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/tutorial.html#setting-up-the-documentation-sources. Thanks for your help.